# Extract a part of keys values in array php

Tags: php, arrays, extract

For some reason I have a array of this kind, and I want to extract the 2 first part of each key,Some of the key contain 5 pieces of string separated by ',' while other contain 2 pieces of string separated y a ','
Ex:

```
array (
    'kksgzgg , kdhdhk',
    'jjj , jjd , jsjs , sjsj , jjsjs',
    'kksksk , kdkdkk',
    'jjj , jjd , jdjdjdj , jjd , jdjdjddj',
    'jjj , jjd , jdjdj , jjsj , sjsjsj',
    'jjj , jjd'
);
```

I need as result an like this with just 2 elements in each key(separated by a comma):

```
Array ( 
    [0] => kksgzgg , kdhdhk 
    [1] => jjj , jjd  
    [2] => kksksk , kdkdkk  
    [3] => jjj , jjd  
    [4] => jjj , jjd  
    [5] => jjj , jjd  
)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the following functions:

- [`implode` — Join array elements with a string](http://php.net/implode)
- [`explode` — Split a string by string](http://php.net/explode)
- [`array_slice` — Extract a slice of the array](http://php.net/array_slice)

**Example:**

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($oldArray as $value) {
    $newArray[] = implode(',', array_slice(explode(',', $value, 3), 0, 2));
}

print_r($newArray);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => kksgzgg , kdhdhk
    [1] => jjj , jjd 
    [2] => kksksk , kdkdkk
    [3] => jjj , jjd 
    [4] => jjj , jjd 
    [5] => jjj , jjd
)
```

**Explanation:**

The code inside the `foreach` can be rewritten with temp variables, which probably makes it easier to understand what's happening. The following code is equivalent to the one-liner above:

```
$parts         = explode(',', $value, 3);
$subsetOfParts = array_slice($parts, 0, 2);
$gluedTogether = implode(',', $subsetOfParts);
$newArray[]    = $gluedTogether;
```

These four lines are applied to all the values in your array one by one during the `foreach`. Let's assume we are doing this for this `$value`:

```
'jjj , jjd , jsjs , sjsj , jjsjs'
```

The first line will split the value by a comma. The third argument `3` controls how many elements you will get in `$parts`:

```
[0 => 'jjj ', [1] => ' jjd ', [2] => ' jsjs , sjsj , jjsjs']
```

The second line will create a new array from `$parts` which only contains the first and second elements, so the result will be

```
[0 => 'jjj ', [1] => ' jjd ']
```

The third line will glue the the subset of parts back together with a comma, so you get

```
'jjj , jjd'
```

That string is then added to `$newArray`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to my other solution would be to use

- [`preg_replace` — Perform a regular expression search and replace](http://php.net/preg_replace)

**Example:**

```
$newArray = preg_replace(
    '/
        (             # capture any string
            [^,]*     # that is not a comma
            ,         # up to a comma
            [^,]*     # followed by any character not a comma
        )             # into group $1
        .*            # followed by any amount of characters
    /x',
    '$1',
    $oldArray
);
```

Without the inline documentation:

```
$newArray = preg_replace('/([^,]*,[^,]*).*/', '$1', $oldArray);
```

Comment: Related: [What is the Official Etiquette on answering a question twice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$clean_array = array();

foreach($array as $value) {
    $clean_array[] = implode(',', array_slice(explode(',' $value), 0, 2);
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($clean_array, true), '</pre>';
```